# Changing colour of texture painted model, after painting

Tags: texture-painting

So I have go through and texture painted a model and afterward we decided we want a colour to be less pink and more red. Is there anyway to adjust just that colour, or do I need to repaint the model?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use a Color > RGB Curves node in order to change the color but it will change the whole image colors (if you add red it will also add red in the blue areas and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Not a pixel-perfect solution, but it works decently well and it's procedural so you don't have to edit the image. You can use a HSV Separation and some simple Math nodes to change just a hue range on an image:
[image: For example, let's change the pink on this image...]

[image: to red]

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thanks for the comment. I will give that a shot and see if it could work for my model. 

Take care